# How Exactly $(document.ready()) function works?

Tags: jquery, document-ready

I successfully changed the source of an `iframe` by writing a jQuery script on `$(document.ready())` to change the `src` attribute from "http://tobechangedurl.com"
to "http://newurl.com"

Below is the `iframe` element:

```html
<p><iframe width="748" height="475" frameborder="0" src="http://tobechangedurl.com" style="margin-left: 50px;"></iframe></p>
```

and it works fine. But, I would like to know when exactly a `document.ready` function gets triggered, there was a time when I was doubting the change  will not  work as I was thinking the `iframe` will load the *tobechangedurl* and then the script will change the `src` to *newurl*.

Comment: RTD: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: when the entire page is loaded

Answer (score 0):

$(document.ready()) is jQuery detecting the state of readiness.

This only occurs once the entire page is ready for JavaScript.

I recommend reading about the jQuery library here: https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/ this could also help you discover more about it.

I hope this helps!